# Unable to restart glassfish 3 server

Tags: java, glassfish-3

We have deployed application on `glassfish3` server on Windows machine.
The server and application were running fine. In the glassfish console, I restarted the server but it didn't start again.

I also tried from the command prompt(as administrator) but getting below error log:

---

> C:\glassfish3\glassfish\bin> asadmin -p 4841 start-domain domain1
>   Waiting for domain1 to start ..Error starting domain domain1. The
>   server exited prematurely with exit code 1. Before it died, it
>   produced the following output:
>
> Launching GlassFish on Felix platform ERROR: Error parsing system
>   bundle export statement: org.osgi.framework; version=1.6.0,
>   org.osgi.framework.launch; versi on=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.wiring;
>   version=1.0.0, org.osgi.framework.startlevel; version=1.0.0,
>   org.osgi.framework.hoo ks.bundle; version=1.0.0,
>   org.osgi.framework.hooks.resolver; version=1.0.0,
>   org.osgi.framework.hooks.service; version=1.
>   1.0, org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving; version=1.0.0, org.osgi.service.packageadmin; version=1.2.0, org.osgi.service.sta
>   rtlevel; version=1.1.0, org.osgi.service.url; version=1.0.0,
>   org.osgi.util.tracker; version=1.5.0, , org.glassfish.embed
>   dable;org.glassfish.embeddable.spi;version=3.1.1
>   (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be
>   z ero length.) ERROR: Unable to re-install
>   file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/javax.transaction.jar
>   (org.osgi.framework.BundleExcept ion: Could not create bundle object.)
>   ERROR: Unable to re-install
>   file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/webservices-extra-jdk-packages.jar
>   (org.osgi.framework .BundleException: Could not create bundle object.)
>   ERROR: Unable to re-install
>   file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/flashlight-extra-jdk-packages.jar
>   (org.osgi.framework. BundleException: Could not create bundle object.)
>   ERROR: Unable to re-install
>   file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/glassfish-corba-omgapi.jar
>   (org.osgi.framework.BundleE xception: Could not create bundle object.)
>   ERROR: Unable to re-install
>   file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/glassfish-extra-jre-packages.jar
>   (org.osgi.framework.B undleException: Could not create bundle object.)
>   ERROR: Unable to re-install
>   file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/glassfish-oracle-jdbc-driver-packages.jar
>   (org.osgi.fr amework.BundleException: Could not create bundle object.)
>   ERROR: Bundle jaxb-api [2] Error starting
>   file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/endorsed/jaxb-api-osgi.jar
>   (org.osgi.fra mework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle
>   jaxb-api [2]: Unable to resolve 2.0: missing requirement [2.0] o
>   sgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.activation)) ERROR:
>   Bundle org.glassfish.metro.webservices-api-osgi [3] Error starting
>   file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/endorsed
>   /webservices-api-osgi.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException:
>   Unresolved constraint in bundle org.glassfish.metro.webse
>   rvices-api-osgi [3]: Unable to resolve 3.0: missing requirement [3.0]
>   osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.
>   xml.bind)(version>=2.2.0)) [caused by: Unable to resolve 2.0: missing
>   requirement [2.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wirin
>   g.package=javax.activation)]) ERROR: Bundle
>   org.glassfish.main.core.glassfish [101] Error starting
>   file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar 
>   (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle
>   org.glassfish.main.core.glassfish [101].) ERROR: Bundle
>   org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-adapter [202] Error starting
>   file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/osgi-adapter.jar 
>   (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle
>   org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-adapter [202]: Unable to re solve 202.0:
>   missing requirement [202.0] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.enterprise.module)(version>
>   =1.1.0)) [caused by: Unable to resolve 121.0: missing requirement [121.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=or
>   g.jvnet.hk2.config)(version>=1.1.0)) [caused by: Unable to resolve
>   37.0: missing requirement [37.0] osgi.wiring.package;  (osgi.wiring.package=javax.management)]])  ....  ....

Comment: What java version are you using? 8 or 7?

Comment: version 7.
Earlier today everything was working fine. We just restarted from the glassfish console and then getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: Have you tried to restart the server and try to start glassfish again?

Comment: Restart from glassfish window didn't work.

After that I tried from command prompt (as administrator):

asadmin -p 4841 start-domain domain1

which prints the above error log

Comment: Have you tried to restart the Windows machine?

Comment: Yes. Restarting the server and will after this as well.

Could it be related to some permission / access rights ?

Comment: Can you paste more error output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was installing Glassfish 3 (coming with JAVA EE 6) when I have configure JAVA_HOME for Java 8. The solution was to modify ./glassfish/config/asenv.conf and set AS_JAVA to point to Java 7

Answer (score 4):

The issue has been resolved.
There are 2 java versions installed on the server. I changed asenv.bat file by adding AS_JAVA option pointing to java 7 and it worked.

Comment: This is what I initially asked you about - the versions of Java, since this is one of the reasons when glasfish 3 glassfish 4 don't work ))).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue after  separately installing java8 and Glassfish3, chaged the `jre-1.6=\` in the /glassfish/config/osgi.properties in (line 205) to `jre-1.8=\` voila it worked

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is an error with your OSGi cache. Go to `${GlassFish_Home}/glassfish/domains/domain1/osgi-cache/` and delete everything in the directory. Alternatively, you could also just delete the directory itself (it will be recreated).