# Glassfish server not starting correctly

Tags: java, netbeans, vaadin, glassfish-3

I'm trying to run a Vaadin web application project on Netbeans using a Glassfish 3 server; when running the project, the build was successful, with no failure messages whatsoever in the output. So, I thought that it might just be the Glassfish server, and after a some scouting, I arrived at this website:

https://www.omniprogrammer.com/?p=324

I followed through to the last step, and attempted to start my Glassfish server accordingly. However, the error log that popped up definitely showed me that this was unsuccessful; the actual text is super long, so I'll just provide a link to it here (and plus I keep on getting "your post appears to contain code" message when I tried to paste it directly, despite the fact that it's obviously not code):

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NMu1qWcPG_uLp3dKlXjbg8X3WnK6XNdY6k4UxSiZAo8/edit?usp=sharing

Obviously, something was wrong here, compounded with the fact that after about 10 minutes, an error message popped up saying "Glassfish server failed to start". I tried to remedy these errors, and the closest thing I found was this:

[Unable to restart glassfish 3 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212488/unable-to-restart-glassfish-3-server)

As such, I tried modifying the glassfish asenv files (both the bat file and and conf file) to point at Java 6 (I have multiple versions installed: 6, 8, and 10). Also, I know in that particular post that they were talking about Java 7, but I'm pretty sure from [Glassfish 3.1 returns an error when started Unable to start server due following issues: Launch process failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578426/glassfish-3-1-returns-an-error-when-started-unable-to-start-server-due-following) that Glassfish 3 supports Java 6. Unfortunately, this still proved ineffective, and the error message was still the same when I tried to start the Glassfish server. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, managed to find a solution to that specific problem; in the server properties, shown below:

[image]

Under the Java tab, I changed the Java platform from JDK 1.8 to 1.6 (1.6 wasn't formerly an option, had to go through "Manage Platforms" and then add JDK 1.6 manually). I don't know if changing the asenv files was also necessary, but at the very least, making both of those changes was sufficient for the error log to clear out.